# Monitor power status on laptop (Windows 10)

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

Sometimes I notice my laptop is losing battery power despite being hooked up to the power adapter. Also, sometimes while gaming the game becomes laggy for a short amount of time.

I would like to confirm or rule out a problem with a loose power socket. Is it possible to monitor a change in the laptop's power supply (windows event viewer?) or a change of the power plan? Once I notice a drained battery and/or the decreased performance while using the machine, I could confirm my suspicion by looking for the appropriate events in the windows logs.

Thanks!

Comment: No event is generated but see [so] question [Logging power / battery events](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18514076) for a vb script.

Comment: Also most laptops offer an option to receive beep warnings during plugging on and off. Check your BIOS to see if yours have that.